# android edittext with alertdialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have `EditText` that, when I click on it, it shows a dialog list of some items. Now when I click on an item I want the item which I select to automatically be entered in the `EditText`. Help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

code of alert dialog

```
public void alert(View view) {

/*
 * WebView is created programatically here.
 *
 * @Here are the list of items to be shown in the list
 */
    final CharSequence[] items = { "John", "Michael", "Vincent", "Dalisay" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddNewDish.this);
    builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
           // String items = quantity.getText().toString();
            // will toast your selection
           // showToast("Name: " + items[item]);
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    }).show();
}
```

code of edittext

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:onClick="alert"
    android:id="@+id/dish_quantity"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dish_name"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Quantity" />
```

like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have reference to the `EditText` that you want to write to, simply add the code to write to it in you `onClick()` method.

The way to write text to an `EditText` is as follows `yourEditText.setText("Your text");`. So in your case, just set the text to your selected item.. i.e. `yourEditText.setText(items[item]);`.

Let me know if this helps, or if you have any other issues/questions!

Comment: yes i also want user on select from alertdialog list item dont type in edittext

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.. Does my answer not cover that?

Comment: yes answer is right but i dont wana allow user to type in edittext manualy on select from list item

Comment: only select from list of item

Comment: Oh, okay. You can accomplish that by setting enabled to false on your `EditText` as follows: `editText.setEnabled(false);`.

Comment: its not working when i click on edittext nothing happend not alertdialog open

Comment: If you never want the user to be able to edit the text, then do it wherever you are initializing the EditText. You could even set the `Enabled` attribute to `false` in your XML layout if this is what you want. If you still need to listen for clicks on the EditText AND you never want the user to be able to edit it manually, maybe you should use a TextView instead.

Comment: but when i do this and click on edit text alertdailog not open how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

This one:

```
final EditText yourEditTextView =(EditText)findViewById(R.id. dish_quantity);
final CharSequence[] items = { "John", "Michael", "Vincent", "Dalisay" };
 builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            yourEditTextView.setText(items[item].toString());
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    }).show()
```

Comment: i also want user on select from alertdialog list item dont type in edittext